# Making JSESSIONID secure creating an issue for login issue from no-secure context

Tags: java, security, jsp, session

I have secured JSESSIONID and also make it HttpOnly. Now problem comes, I can not able to login in my application from unsecured page(http protocol). Is there any way to move from secure page(https) to unsecured page(http) or vice versa if JSEESIONID is secured and HttpOnly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to move from secure page(https) to unsecured page(http) or vice versa if JSEESIONID is `secure`

Not with a single cookie. The whole point of `secure` is to *stop* the cookie being sent in the clear to an HTTP page, where an eavesdropper can purloin it and use it to access the HTTPS page.

To have a system where compromise of an HTTP cookie didn't break the HTTPS cookie too, you'd have to have two separate session cookies with different names and values. eg: an `http_session` cookie, without `secure` that only the HTTP version of the site reads, and an `https_session` cookie, with `secure`, that only the HTTPS version reads. The login process would have to set both cookies, and the session system would have to be tinkered with to tie both session IDs to the same bag of session storage.

> I can not able to login in my application from unsecured page

You **must not** allow login from an HTTP page. Even if the form submission is going securely to an HTTPS address, there is no way for the end-user to tell that this is the case, so a man-in-the-middle attacker can easily tamper with the login form to make it leak the password before the HTTPS connection is ever made. HTTP login forms are a classic security mistake.

In general, swapping between HTTP and HTTPS inside a site is very difficult to get right, without compromising security or reliability. It is rarely worth it. If you have an HTTPS address, you are usually best off serving everything through that address only.